# Change Opacity of complete EditText when focus changes

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to have a custom `EditText` where the opacity of the **complete** `EditText` changes depending on focus.

Here an example:

[image]

The top `EditText` is unfocused and the bottom `EditText` is focused. So as you can see the opacity of the icon, the text and the underlining is different.

How can i create such a behaviour for a custom android `EditText`?

Comment: register an onFocusChangedListener and change the colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I haven't missed the point of your question. I'm assuming you know how to change the icon and the color of the hint.

Your EditText can implement OnFocusChangeListener

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText implements OnFocusChangeListener
```

Then in the constructors of your custom edit text you call

```
super.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

And in the listener:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        setColorsWhenFocus();
    } else {
        setColorsWhenNoFocus();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Since your question is about a simple native way to change the opacity of the entire edittext when it has got the focus, I think the answer is that this is not possible because it goes against the design guidelines

Comment: I hoped to get arround too much work for that simple purpose. Since all colors of the EditText are black when its focused and a slightly transparent black when its not focused i hoped that there is an easy way to just set the transparency of the complete edittext. Thank you.

Comment: I see ok. BTW are you sure that's what you want? Why don't you follow the guidelines about edittext? Please search for TextInputLayout

Comment: It is a design i got. I just have to implement it as it is. Since Designers have no idea about implementation they design what tey want and expect to get it ^^

Comment: And they normally know only about  iOS design guidelines and not Android.